# App can not be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: macos, code-signing

### Question:

**Please note before reading this that:** "Tell them to go to `System preferences > Security & privacy` and `allow 3rd party applications to run`. Is not an acceptable solve for this issue.

I have created an `.app` That has been signed with a valid Mac Developer certificate. Yet downloading it from the internet & running still throws the security prompt:

> App can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

This is the `codesign -vvv` terminal dump for the `.app`:

```
Executable=/Users/me/Desktop/ADRA.app/Contents/MacOS/ADRA
Identifier=unity.Company.ADRA NSW 2016
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (i386)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=178145 flags=0x0(none) hashes=5561+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=79ecf88721d6387749c1f6b10355c3683ef20eb2
CandidateCDHash sha256=0799e968a18a663a0c08d26d3fb7826017ce5a3a
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CDHash=0799e968a18a663a0c08d26d3fb7826017ce5a3a
Signature size=4739
Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Company Pty Ltd (NH73TNDB28)
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=20 Apr 2017, 2:46:12 PM
Info.plist entries=14
TeamIdentifier=NH73TNDB28
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=138
Internal requirements count=1 size=224
```

I don't understand why this does not pass Gatekeeper? Is there something missing? Does Apple require further payments / bribes or something?

---

### Update 1:

@TheDarkKnight has suggested that I am using the incorrect certificate to sign the `.app`. Looks as though they are correct, so I went to create a new `Developer ID Application certificate` but apparently because I am not an 'Agent' in the group account, so I now have to wait until the 'Agent' creates one for me - seems backwards, is there no other way around waiting for the 'Agent' to make this for me?

> (in Xcode) If the "Developer ID" radio button is greyed out you probably have a group account. **These types of accounts only allow for the "Agent" role to create Developer IDs.** Contact the person who created your group Apple Developer Account if you get stuck here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Signing_Mozilla_apps_for_Mac_OS_X

---

### Update 2:

So I finally got my new cert today, re-signed the `.app`, downloaded it from the server ran and **STILL GOT THE ERROR MESSAGE**. The authority seems to be correct now:

```
Executable=/Users/me/Downloads/ADRA.app/Contents/MacOS/ADRA
Identifier=com.company.adra
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (i386)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=178133 flags=0x0(none) hashes=5561+3 location=embedded
Library validation warning=OS X SDK version before 10.9 does not support Library Validation
OSPlatform=36
OSSDKVersion=657408
OSVersionMin=656896
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=90d2a54162d6d018bf4f7602d7707c8e8e522fc6
CandidateCDHash sha256=dadfe5203d1367ea776f9501025dbd4ce751ee30
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
Page size=4096
CDHash=dadfe5203d1367ea776f9501025dbd4ce751ee30
Signature size=8930
Authority=Developer ID Application: Company Pty Ltd (NH73TNDB28)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=10 May 2017, 3:36:51 pm
Info.plist entries=14
TeamIdentifier=NH73TNDB28
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=138
Internal requirements count=1 size=184
```

I am only signing the `.app` is there anything else that I have to do to make this work? Is there a time period I have to wait before this will work?

Comment: *Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Company Pty Ltd (NH73TNDB28)* - is this a self-signed certificate? Developer certificates usually start with "Developer ID Application...". Self-signed certificates should not be allowed by Gatekeeper, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight As in did I create the cert myself? - if that's what you were asking, no I got it from `apple.developer`.

Comment: I think you've got the wrong type of certificate there. It may be worth seeing if there are any other certs, in your Apple Dev account, to download. Looking at all other 3rd party apps on my machines, their cert "Authority" all start with *"Developer ID Application: ..."*

Comment: @TheDarkKnight That's very valuable - thank you, I will look at this first thing in the morning and verify what is going on here.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I just `codesign verified` a bunch of 3rd party apps and you are correct, they all have `Developer ID Application` to start. Looking into getting a new certificate now.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Please see the update for the question - do you have any further insight on this?

Comment: When you double-click on an app bundle to execute your application, the OS will run the application that it has associated with the bundle's identifier, in the plist. If you have more than one version of the same application on the system, it may be trying to execute a different app, instead of the one you're clicking on. Verify that you do not have any copies of the old app on your machine, which was signed with the invalid certificate and has a matching bundle identifier.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight downloaded and tested on a computer which has not previously had the app on it and it still failed. Is there any other information that I can provide that will help solve this?

Comment: How are you codesigning the app; by specifying the certificate in an Xcode project, calling codesign in the terminal, or an alternative method?

Answer (score 4):

Apple supply different certificates for different purposes.

If you look at a signature for an app downloaded from the App Store, you'll see that they usually contain the Common Name: `Apple Mac OS Application Signing`, as Apple re-sign applications that they distribute through the store.

For 3rd party developers that distribute via alternative streams, their **Application certificates** usually have a Common Name that begins with: `"Developer ID Application..."`.

Note that other 3rd party certificates are available, such as an **Installer certificate** for signing installer packages, whose Common Name begins with `"Developer ID Installer..."`.

The privilege of being able to sign a product with a certificate must be limited and tightly controlled.

Should a copy of your certificate be leaked, it can be used for nefarious purposes, such as distribution of malware, as was the case with [KeRanger, which infected the Transmission BitTorrent application](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/03/new-os-x-ransomware-keranger-infected-transmission-bittorrent-client-installer/).

If you suspect a leaked certificate that you own, you need to revoke it, which can be initiated from your Apple Developer account.

So, Apple limits the creation of certificates to the Agent, as there can be only one registered with an Apple Developer account and is the person who has legally agreed to take responsibility for it.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer, I am not at work for the next 4 days, and will let you know how I get on with this. Hopefully as you suggested - I will get the new certificate and this will basically resolve itself.

Comment: Finally got back around to this... I just signed the `.app` with my new cert, downloaded it and **STILL GOT THE ERROR MESSAGE**. I checked the sign and it is correct: 
`Authority=Developer ID Application: Company Pty Ltd (NH73TNDB28)`
`Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority`
`Authority=Apple Root CA`
So what else could it be do you think? I am only signing the `.app` is there anything else I have to sign?

Comment: @Zze ever get this resolved? I'm stuck in a similar situation.

Comment: @spartygw Unfortunately no. I made a cross post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281366/app-can-not-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer but there were endless issues with it and I moved projects before it was resolved.

Comment: @Zze I'm starting to believe that anything downloaded from a browser is going to get the quarantine attribute attached regardless of the code signature. My working theory is that in order for me to distribute my macOS app without the warning popup I have to go through the mac AppStore.

Comment: @spartygw Honestly I wouldn't be surprised. Sounds like something Apple would implement to discourage developers from going away from the AppStore. I downloaded VisualStudio 2019 last night and It gave the exact same warning.

Comment: Actually, coming back to this, @TheDarkKnight was right in his answer. I was building a pkg and signing it with "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" which allowed me to create a pkg but wouldn't pass GateKeeper. If you read TheDarkKnight's answer closer than I did the first time he says to sign with "Developer ID Installer". This was the link I was missing. Once I signed with that cert it passes GateKeeper even after distributing over http and downloading via Chrome. Upvote from me Dark Knight!